# How to convert table column to date type in SQL and arrange in ascending order?

Tags: sql, date

Suppose we have the following column from a table (type: character):

```
date
Wed May 31 21:00:01 +0000 2017
Wed May 31 20:59:59 +0000 2017
```

I'm trying to sort this table by ascending order, but it won't work because it does so alphabetically given that the column type is `character` rather than `date`. Any ideas how to change the type in SQL to `date` so that it will sort properly?

Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also explain why you are storing a date value in string rather than using a proper datetime/timestamp type -- which all databases support.

Comment: The full dataset contains one million+ rows unfortunately. The data I downloaded stored the date value as a string rather than me doing it deliberately, which is why I'm wondering if there's a way to convert to a timestamp type?

Comment: order by cast(stringFromTable as DateTime).  But this will take a LONG time every time you run the query.  You should change the format in the table to be datetime.  Or create 2nd column and update it to be a datetime and format the data into that column, then sort by that.

Comment: @Brad this worked, thank you!

Comment: @HelpMe, I added my comment as answer if you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting answer from comments as poster said that worked

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTableName
ORDER BY CAST(DateInStringFormatFromTable as DateTime)
```

This will take a LONG time every time you run the query.

You should change the format in the table to be datetime. Or create 2nd column and update it to be a datetime and format the data into that column, then sort by that.

Updated to give other option based off comments:

You can try convert, instead of cast to see if that works for your decending

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTableName
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, DateInStringFormatFromTable, 102) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you also include how to make this return in descending order? I tried `DESC` at the end of the query but the order didn't change for some reason.

Comment: ORDER BY CAST(DateInStringFormatFromTable as DateTime) DESC     This should work.

Comment: I thought so too but it doesn't strangely

Comment: I tested on a sample table in my DB (MS SQL 2012) and it worked. You have the DESC  outside the cast?

Comment: Yes, outside the cast so strange (using a package in R Studio to run SQL code). Is there an alternative way to select the date in the very last row without using DESC to rearrange and selecting top row as usual?

Comment: As stated above you should store this as date format in your table as it will make all this way easier.  I updated my answer to use convert as well, you can try that.  If the DESC still does not work and if you just want the highest date (and not any other data) you can try this (if it works because the sort DESC is not) is to Select MAX(cast(DateInStringFormatFromTable as DATEIMTE ) FromTableName